# BottomSheetScaffold auto-expand sheetContent in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose-text

In Jetpack Compose, how to automatically expand the `sheetContent` of `BottomSheetScaffold`?

```kotlin
BottomSheetScaffold(
        topBar = {},
        sheetContent = { CommentView(navController, wind) }) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, so simple

```kotlin
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    scope.launch {
        scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
    }
```